# Comparing type when you have a System.Type

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have the following delegate:

```
Action<string, object, Type> IsA = 
    (name, candidate, target) => 
    {
        Write("Is " + name + " a " + target.Name + "? " + (candidate.GetType() is target));
    };
```

It is supposed to return whether the candidate IS-A target.  However, target is now a variable of System.Type.

How can I say whether `candidate` IS-A `target`?

Comment: Do you want to include subclasses or just perfect matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do just simple comparsion:

```
candidate.GetType() == target;
```

It will check if canditate is exactly of type that is specified in `target`.
If you want to include subclasses/interfaces you can write:

```
target.IsAssignableFrom(candidate.GetType());
```

It works like `is` keyword, but operates on `Type` class, not concrete instances.

You should also check if `candidate` is not null - in that case `GetType` will throw `NullReferenceException` exception.

Comment: `target.IsAssignableFrom(candidate.GetType());` is what I was looking for.    Cheers!